# Cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32 exception in Java on Centos 7

Tags: java, netbeans, centos7

I installed netbeans 8.2 on Centos 7.

I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor: DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop : cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:135)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.<clinit>(DragSource.java:148)
```

Java version :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b15, mixed mode)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

1- Edit following file:

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

2- Replace `rhgb quiet` to `nomodeset`.

3- Run on terminal `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

4- Reboot.

Actually this not solve the problem. It's only ignore it.

Comment: This is more like a workaround with several possible side effects (some really nasty) depending on the actual hardware. The real solution is posted by @tron_at, update your JRE/JDK.

Answer (score 5):

I had the problem on Kali in virtualbox.

If your OS is in virtualbox, the solotion is shutdown the OS.

Then turn off "**Enable 3D Acceleration**" under Machine -> Settings -> Dispaly.

Start your OS and enjoy！

Comment: I had the sam issue using Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox with macOS as the host. I disabled 3D acceleration and now it's working fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with Ubuntu inside VirtualBox for another application. Disabling 3D acceleration solved the problem, but made everything related to graphic sluggish. The actual problem, it turned out, was that I was using an old guest additions installation. When I installed the the guest additions corresponding to the VirtualBox version I was using, everything started working as it should without disabling 3D acceleration.

Comment: save my life 

Answer (score 5):

It seems the bug is solved with java 8u152 b05. 
The following code passes 8u152, but throws the mentioned exception using Java 8u131:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DragSource.getDefaultDragSource(); 
}
```

Currently 8u152 is available in "JDK 8 Updates Early-Access Builds":
http://jdk.java.net/8/

Comment: As a reference, the bug involved is https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173853)

Comment: It helped! Thanks. I had jdk_121 installed. After update the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

My Java code uses Drag&Drop in JTree, which get broken after upgrade from CentOS 6 to CentOS 7. Same hardware, same OpenJDK, same Java code, but different graphic driver. The workaround with kernel command line setting "nomodeset" helps, but causes poor graphic & flickering.
Here is a pure Java workaround:

```
  //workaround for used Drag&Drop cursors which are unsupported by graphics driver
  public static void initUnsupportedCursors() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
  {
    String cursors[] = new String[]{
        "DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop",
        "DnD.Cursor.MoveDrop",
        "DnD.Cursor.LinkDrop",
        "DnD.Cursor.CopyNoDrop",
        "DnD.Cursor.MoveNoDrop",
        "DnD.Cursor.LinkNoDrop"
        };
   List <String> unsupportedCursors =  new ArrayList <String>(); 
   for (String c : cursors)
   {
     try
     {
       if (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty(c) == null)
       {
         throw new Exception("Can't find cursor " + c);
       }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       unsupportedCursors.add(c);
     }
   }
   if (!unsupportedCursors.isEmpty())
   {
     Field propsFiled = Toolkit.class.getDeclaredField("desktopProperties");
     propsFiled.setAccessible(true);
     Map props = (Map) propsFiled.get(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit());
     for (String unsupportedCursor : unsupportedCursors)
     {
       System.out.println("Replacing unsupported " + unsupportedCursor + " by " + Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
       props.put(unsupportedCursor, Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice though.

Comment: The root problem is the "Could not initialize class java.awt.dnd.DragSource" Exception which was thrown due to Exception in load("DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop").
See java.awt.dnd.DragSource, line 147:
public static final Cursor DefaultCopyDrop = load("DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop");
The code above is a workaround for the problem - it iterates over all cursors of java.awt.dnd.DragSource and set Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR  in java.awt.Toolkit.desktopProperties map  in case of exception.
The desktopProperties member of java.awt.Toolkit is protected, it is a reason for the usage of "elegant" reflection solution.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported as a bug : [Bug 257554 - RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor: DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop : cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257554)

It turns out that it is linked to a reported bug in Unity-Mir : [Java applications are missing X11 resources - XQueryBestCursor return 0,0](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-mir/+bug/1250613).

From the comments , the JDK version along with the old XMir (which is not supported anymore) was responsible of that .
Anyway, it is fixed by the last XMir versions.

> This would be a bug in Java, where it is unable to deal with the Xorg
>   software cursor. Which is a problem unrelated to Mir really. Mir just
>   puts X in a (valid) mode where the bug is triggered.
>
> Although, we could work around the Java bug by implementing full
>   hardware cursor support in XMir...

and

> XMir 1.0 (the old Xorg extension) is now deprecated and is not being
>   maintained or fixed. It is replaced by the new 'Xmir' binary (package
>   'xmir') introduced in Ubuntu 15.10 wily.

and

> Note: The new Xmir uses the hardware cursor (where available on
>   desktop). So if this bug still exists at all, it would only be on
>   mobile (Android Mir platform).

You should consider upgrading to the "new" version.